# What's the best way of storing application data in Android?

Tags: java, android

Suppose you were writing an app that stored a large, ordered data structure that remains static through the life of the application. What's the best way of including that kind of data in your Android app?

(In my particular case, I'm working on a Unicode character map, and I need a place to stick data about the characters to display.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also ship with a pre-created database as discussed in this question: [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Although I think that Andrew's solution is easier to implement since the database comes with it's own set of difficulties.

On the other hand databases are what you would use for "a large, ordered data structure" even if it remains static because access to databases should be faster than file access.